# Tratamento de query grafico via javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, query

Boa tarde, eu tenho uma query em meu sistema onde ela gera um grafico.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira legenda do grafico está como undefined, estava tentando refazer a minha query  só que não estava vindo com os mesmos valores.
**Eu queria retirar a opção undefined que está em minha legenda** deixar somente as três ultimas opções em meu grafico.

Queria saber se alguém pode me ajudar a fazer um tratamento via **javascript**, irei postar meu codigo abaixo. 
**Controller.cs**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetProcessosByDeslocamentoPedidoMedico()
        {
            SetaTipos();
            var dados = string.Empty;

            if (_tipo == 2)
                dados = $"AND p.RegiaoId = {_dado}";
            else if (_tipo == 3)
                dados = $"AND p.UserId = {_dado}";

            var query = $@"SELECT Title, SUM(Count) AS Count
                        FROM (
                            SELECT
                            CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND EstadoId = Meddoc1 AND EstadoId = Meddoc2 AND EstadoId = Meddoc3 THEN
                                 'Sem deslocamento'
                                 ELSE CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId = Meddoc1 OR EstadoId = Meddoc2 OR EstadoId = Meddoc3) THEN
                                    'Fora de domicílio do autor'
                                    ELSE CASE WHEN EstadoId <> EstadoIdAutor OR (EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId <> Meddoc1 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc2 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc3)) THEN
                                        'Mais de um deslocamento'
                                    END
                                 END 
                            END AS Title,
                            COUNT(*) AS Count
                            FROM jud_Processos
                            WHERE Status = 1 AND Trancado = 1 {dados}
                            GROUP BY EstadoId, EstadoIdAutor, Meddoc1, Meddoc2, Meddoc3
                        ) Sub
                        GROUP BY Title;";

            var total = await _graficosService.GetProcessos(query);

            return Json(total, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

meu javascript

```
case "9":
  Post("GetProcessosByDeslocamentoPedidoMedico", "", text);
  break;
```

**Eu queria retirar a opção undefined que está em minha legenda**

Comment: as informações do `JavaScript` que você forneceu são insuficientes para uma resposta.

Comment: Então é somente isso que tem em js não tem como fazer isto pela query? eu fiz uma de cada usei um union all porem os resultados diferentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode filtrar os resultados com uma query superior

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM (
SELECT Title, SUM(Count) AS Count
                        FROM (
                            SELECT
                            CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND EstadoId = Meddoc1 AND EstadoId = Meddoc2 AND EstadoId = Meddoc3 THEN
                                 'Sem deslocamento'
                                 ELSE CASE WHEN EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId = Meddoc1 OR EstadoId = Meddoc2 OR EstadoId = Meddoc3) THEN
                                    'Fora de domicílio do autor'
                                    ELSE CASE WHEN EstadoId <> EstadoIdAutor OR (EstadoId = EstadoIdAutor AND (EstadoId <> Meddoc1 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc2 AND EstadoId <> Meddoc3)) THEN
                                        'Mais de um deslocamento'
                                    END
                                 END 
                            END AS Title,
                            COUNT(*) AS Count
                            FROM jud_Processos
                            WHERE Status = 1 AND Trancado = 1 {dados}
                            GROUP BY EstadoId, EstadoIdAutor, Meddoc1, Meddoc2, Meddoc3
                        ) Sub
                        GROUP BY Title
) TB_AUX;
```

Comment: Funcionou cara, muito obrigado